# How Can I Download A File Without Revealing Passwords?

Tags: curl, vagrant, puppet, wget

I have a vagrant/puppet project in source control that requires some dependencies to be downloaded.
However, these dependencies are on a password protected nexus instance.

If I use wget with `--username` and `--password` I can download the files, however, I can't check in my username and password to source control.

I don't want to ask people to make modifications to the source files (by putting in their usernames/passwords) after they check out as I prefer projects to just run.

Is it possible to use an encrypted password with wget or curl?

I can't just set permissions on a file as it is a vagrant box and developers will have full root access.

Comment: you could have an additional properties file where users will put their login/password and your Vagrantfile will read from this file so dev will not touch source file but an external file, you could also have additional specific setting in this file

Answer (score 0):

This isn't something that you can do out of the box with WGET or cURL. One way you could seek to do this is have a proxy; you request the site, that server in turn requests the file from a separate server and passes it to the visitor.

In short: **no**.